# PHP MySQL Unknown column '.....' in 'field list' using alias

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My Table 'product_stock' has the Column 'Quantity'

Yet I get the error

> Unknown column 'product_stock.Quantity' in 'field list'

from the dollowing query

```
$sql="SELECT *,COALESCE(SUM(product_stock.Quantity), 0) as balance FROM product_stock p 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM sales st
) AS T 
  ON p.product_stock_ProductId = T.ProductId
GROUP BY 
  p.ProductId, 
  p.ProductName";
```

Breaking my head over what is wrong here....any help will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Any chance you have multiple databases running and you're referencing the incorrect one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already aliased `product_stock` to `p`, you should consistently use that alias when referring to columns in the same table.  Also, another common error in your query is doing `SELECT *` in a `GROUP BY`.  You should only select columns which appear in the `GROUP BY` clause or are inside aggregate functions.

```sql
SELECT
    p.ProductId,
    p.ProductName,
    COALESCE(SUM(p.Quantity), 0) AS balance
FROM product_stock p
LEFT JOIN sales s
    ON p.product_stock_ProductId = s.ProductId
GROUP BY 
    p.ProductId,
    p.ProductName;
```